# Regex - Pattern finds parts of itself with (.+)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In C#, I have the following Regex pattern (on an HTML string):

```
Regex TR = new Regex(@"<tr class=""(\w+)""  rel=""(\w+)"">(.+)</tr>");
```

The problem is, that when I run it, the match includes everything until the last `</tr>` occurrence in the HTML code. There are many `<tr>` tags in the code, so the `(.+)` pattern includes them and stops only in the last occurrence of `</tr>`.

I've tried using `(\w+)` instead, but it doesn't get certain characters inside the tags.

So how can I make this pattern stop at the first `</tr>`, and not go until the last one in the code?

Comment: Reading on the subject: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/335858)

Comment: `.+?` ......... BTW: Use https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ instead of regex

Comment: Try `.*?` instead of `.+`.

Comment: @Eser - It works! Thank you very much!

Can you please explain to me how `?` works in Regex? I saw it mentioned on a website but didn't understand how exactly it makes the Regex go only until the first occurence of `<\tr>` in this specific case.

Comment: @BlueRay101 search for *non-greedy* match.

Comment: @Eser, I read about it and understood it. Thanks for your help! I'll also check out the HTML agility pack.

Comment: Playing with [balancing feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) of .NET [tried this](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=e1e26b38-eba5-4778-b615-2a5a2bb55dbc) as [explained here](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2003/05/15/nested-constructs-in-regular-expressions/), but sure better to use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex pattern will stop at the first `</tr>` tag:

```
<tr(\s+)class(\s*)=(\s*)"[^"]*"(\s+)rel(\s*)=(\s*)"[^"]*"(\s*)>(.(?!<\/tr>))*[\s\S]<\/tr>
```

You can change your code into following to get what you wanted:

```
Regex TR = new Regex(@"<tr class=""(\w+)""  rel=""(\w+)"">(.(?!<\/tr>))*[\s\S]</tr>");
```

`(?!ABC)` is called **negative lookahead**. It specifies a group that can not match after the main expression (if it matches, the result is discarded).

For future reference: Try using [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) to create and test your regex patterns.

Answer (score -1):

```
> So how can I make this pattern stop at the first </tr>
```

The most effective capturing process paradigm is to not consume blindly, but consume what is known.

Since the text to grab falls within the anchors of `>` and `<`, why not use that logic of the ending anchor, the `<`, to give the regex parser a hint?

By using the `^` character (*it is the **not** in a set*) in a set `[ ]` we effectively tell the parser to consume until a specific set of character(s) is hit.

In your case change

```
>(.+)</tr>
```

to `[^<]+` which says consume *everything* until (or except for) when the `<` character is hit, one or more times:

```
>([^<]+)</tr>
```

The use of the `[^ ]` set is a powerful one which I use in 90% of my regex patterns instead of blinding consuming with `.+` or the even more side affect prone `.*`.

---

Also to make your pattern easier to handle use `\x22` in lieu of `"` so you are not fighting with the C# parser before the regex parser.